# What is the $subject in the Symfony GenericEvent?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-eventdispatcher

The [`GenericEvent`](http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/GenericEvent.html) of the [`symfony/event-dispatcher`](https://github.com/symfony/event-dispatcher) package provides two properties -- `subject` and `arguments`. If I understand the [docu](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/generic_event.html) correctly, the `arguments` can be used for passing context data into the `Event` object. But I'm not getting, how to use the other property.

**How is the `GenericEvent#subject` intended to be used?**

Answer (score 0):

Look at this artikel: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/generic_event.html

You can get the Subject with getSubject() and pass it. But more usefull it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a 'subject line', as an object that can be attached. The type of the property in the documentation is 'mixed', not 'string', or in other words - anything.

So, hit can be used as "here's the subject of the event, and some arguments about what to do with it."